# Cv2 vs opencv contrib google colab: Can't use opencv contrib

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, opencv

i'm trying to load cv2 (contrib) from colab beacuse i need

```
cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
```

but it says

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_superres'
```

using pip install is useless beacuse it says that opencv contrib has already been installed.

So, what can i do to make colab load opencv contrib and not opencv?